# A Plunk implements the desired behavior, but only fully works after typing a character

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is the Plunk:  http://plnkr.co/edit/KXn7vC13zoJsUwQKAA0A?p=preview

Here is the directive I'm interested in, copied directly from the Plunk:

```
.directive('navigatable', function(){
return function(scope, element, attr) {

    element.on('keypress.mynavigation', 'input[type="text"]', handleNavigation);
    function handleNavigation(e){

var arrow = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };

// select all on focus
element.find('input').keydown(function (e) {

    // shortcut for key other than arrow keys
    if ($.inArray(e.which, [arrow.left, arrow.up, arrow.right, arrow.down]) < 0) { return; }

    var input = e.target;
    var td = $(e.target).closest('td');
    var moveTo = null;

    switch (e.which) {

        case arrow.left: {
            if (input.selectionStart == 0) {
                moveTo = td.prev('td:has(input,textarea)');
            }
            break;
        }
        case arrow.right: {
            if (input.selectionEnd == input.value.length) {
                moveTo = td.next('td:has(input,textarea)');
            }
            break;
        }

        case arrow.up:
        case arrow.down: {

            var tr = td.closest('tr');
            var pos = td[0].cellIndex;

            var moveToRow = null;
            if (e.which == arrow.down) {
                moveToRow = tr.next('tr');
            }
            else if (e.which == arrow.up) {
                moveToRow = tr.prev('tr');
            }

            if (moveToRow.length) {
                moveTo = $(moveToRow[0].cells[pos]);
            }

            break;
        }

    }

    if (moveTo && moveTo.length) {

        e.preventDefault();

        moveTo.find('input,textarea').each(function (i, input) {
            input.focus();
            input.select();
        });

    }

});


        var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if(key === 13){
            var focusedElement = $(e.target);
            var nextElement = focusedElement.parent().next();
            if (nextElement.find('input').length>0){
                nextElement.find('input').focus();
            }else{
                nextElement = nextElement.parent().next().find('input').first();
                nextElement.focus();
            }
        }
    }
};
})
```

I found it through this question (thank you):  [Keyboard navigation in AngularJS table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430830/keyboard-navigation-in-angularjs-table/23467514#23467514?newreg=411ceff8418545f2af243d4d1d3f9fb6)

Everything about it is perfect for what I want to do, except one behavior.  Initially, the arrow keys don't work.  Then after I type at least one character, or press enter, then the arrow keys work exactly as I expect.

I put break points on each level of functions to see that the directive returns the whole function when the page is loaded - i.e. when the navigatable HTML table is rendered.  Then I do some actions that create the inputs, and nothing in the directive is invoked by those steps - I suspect that is where something needs to happen.  At that point, the new inputs are not responding to arrow keys.  Once I type a character or press enter, HandleNavigation runs and from that point forward, the arrow keys work on the new inputs.

So my question is, can this be improved such that the arrow keys will work right away after new inputs are created, but no key has been pressed yet?